# How to ignore the top level source folder in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

In my Eclipse project I have two source folders, **src/app** and **src/test**, each of which compiles into its own output folder, **classes/app** and  **classes/test** respectively.

Unfortunately, since they have the same parent directory, **src**, that parent dir is also showing in the package explorer hierarchy in Eclipse.  It is not a big deal but it is redundant and annoying.  See illustration

[image]

Any idea how I can remove src from the view but keep its two relevant subdirectories shown as source folders?  I tried to do it under **Configure Build Path** but couldn't find a way.

Thanks

Comment: Is this Maven built project?

Comment: @brano88, no, i plan to use Ant

Comment: So...this is manualy made project, right?

Comment: yes, indeed -- manually created but will later use ant for building and jaring etc.

Comment: Maybe use eclipse's customize working set and apply filters

Answer (score 0):

You can't, appart from developping your own plugin.

The closest thing you can have is to click on the withe arrow next to the 2 yellow ones
[image: here]

And go to filters and finally check "non java elements", but I suspect the ant file will be hidden too.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use the view menu of the Package Explorer View, select Filters, check "Non Java Elements". This will hide other non Java projects in the same workspace, so use with caution.

Comment: I didn't down vote you, but for me, this hides too much stuff to be useful.